# SDWebImageManager not showing image from long and special character URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, sdwebimage

SDWebImage not displaying image from URL which is too long and with some special characters.

image URL is:

http://akns-images.eonline.com/eol_images/Entire_Site/2018223/rs_600x600-180323073745-600-michael-davidson-fdny-032218.jpg?fit=around%7C450:350&crop=450:350;center,top&output-quality=100

```
[albumImageview sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aboveURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:placeholder] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you try to set it up?

Comment: @AleksandrHoncharov check the code.

Comment: Your image url should end in .jpg (or .png or whatever). Did you try without `?fit=around%7C450:350&crop=450:350;center,top&output-quality=100`?

Comment: @Kevinosaurio  So SDWebImage need .png at the last of URL?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. But In my past experience, I saw that the image don't download if the url end with other format.

Comment: @Parthpatel1105 check my answer and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method

```
[albumImageview sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://akns-images.eonline.com/eol_images/Entire_Site/2018223/rs_600x600-180323073745-600-michael-davidson-fdny-032218.jpg?fit=around%7C450:350&crop=450:350;center,top&output-quality=100"] placeholderImage:[UIImage new] completed:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL * _Nullable imageURL) {
    albumImageview.image = image;
}];
```